How to understand ingress-nginx (Backend Certificate Authentication)
My ingress resource:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-name: <>
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-secret: <>
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-verify: "on"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service
            port:
              number: 8443
        path: /somePath
        pathType: Prefix


I want to understand why does above annotations adds up the proxy_ssl_ directives to default server block + at the location level
$ cat nginx.conf | grep proxy_ssl_verify
                proxy_ssl_verify                        on; //server block
                proxy_ssl_verify_depth                  1;
                        proxy_ssl_verify                        on; // location block
                        proxy_ssl_verify_depth                  1;


My expectation is, it should add only to the location block for whichever ingress resource it is defined.

Figured out the WA for this:
Use below config in the configmap of ingress-controller:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#proxy-ssl-location-only

Figured out the WA for this:
Use below config in the configmap of ingress-controller:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#proxy-ssl-location-only
